# I have 3 forms displayed by checkbox - How can I show only the form that is checked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

So i am making a feed where the user can post a link, text, or image. Each posting uses its own simple form. As of now I can display each form with a checkbox, but I can't figure out how to hide the other forms when another is clicked.

```
<!-- ************************ TEXT POST ************************ -->
<%= simple_form_for @tl_text do |f| %>
  <div id="textpost" style=display:none class="hidden">
    <%= f.text_area :content, label: "512 character limit", placeholder: "512 character limit", :rows => 6, :cols => 30 %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
  <input name="text" id="text_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="yes" />Text &nbsp;
<% end %>

<!-- ************************ LINK POST ************************ -->
<%= simple_form_for @tl_link do |f| %>
  <div id="linkpost" style=display:none class="hidden">
    <%= f.input :link, label: "Please enter link here" %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 6, :cols => 30 %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
  <input name="link" id="link_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="yes" />Link &nbsp;
<% end %>

<!-- ************************ IMAGE POST ************************ -->
<%= simple_form_for @tl_image do |f| %>
  <div id="imagepost" style=display:none class="hidden">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 6, :cols => 30 %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
  <input name="image" id="image_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="yes" />Image &nbsp;
<% end %>

<script>
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    $('#' + this.name + 'post').slideToggle(this.checked)
    $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked', false);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

$checkboxes.on('change', function () {
    $checkboxes.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $form = $this.prev('div');

        this.checked ? $form.slideDown('slow') : $form.slideUp('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: @ChristopherKnight.. Glad to have helped :)